# How to write a text above all columns and near all rows

Tags: tables, matrices, multirow, multicolumn

I have a simple table I wrote as confusion matrix for testing, and I would like to add a title over all columns (like "actual value") and a title near all rows, possibly 90 degrees rotated (like "predicted value"). How can I do that?

My table code is

```
\begin{table}
\centering
 \caption{TITLE}
 \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
 & \textbf{Indoor} & \textbf{Outdoor} & \textbf{Precision} \\
 \hline
\textbf{Indoor} & \textbf{13331} & 202 & \textbf{98.51\%} \\  \hline
\textbf{Outdoor} & 203 & \textbf{5994} & \textbf{96.72\%} \\  \hline
\textbf{Recall} & \textbf{98.50\%} & \textbf{96.74\%} &  \\
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) At least I have trouble understanding what you want. Could you please provide a drawing (handmade would suffice) of what you want? Also could you please turn your code snippet into a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), making it compilable?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{caption, multirow, array}%

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}
 \centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
 \caption{TITLE}
 \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c}
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{Columns title}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\[0.5ex]
 & & \textbf{Indoor} & \textbf{Outdoor} & \textbf{Precision} \\
 \cline{2-5}
 \multirow{3}{*}[0.75em]{\rotatebox[origin = r]{90}{Rows title}} & \textbf{Indoor} & \textbf{13331} & 202 & \textbf{98.51\%} \\
 \cline{2-5}
 & \textbf{Outdoor} & 203 & \textbf{5994} & \textbf{96.72\%} \\
 \cline{2-5}
 & \textbf{Recall} & \textbf{98.50\%} & \textbf{96.74\%} & \\
 \end{tabular}
 \label{tab:test}
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

[image]